# Can I create a drop down list with data from multiple sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

Is it possible to use data from multiple sheets in drop down or data validation in google spreadsheet?

Example:

Highlighted would be name of the sheet.

http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-NLSx-SfDonE/Ul-27CPjnZI/AAAAAAAAEmk/fgDqM70ezVA/s1600/1.png

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrayformula to copy the data from each sheet onto the current sheet as a block of columns, then use a rectangular range to create the drop-down list:

[Screenshot showing multi-sheet drop-down in Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahMdI.png)

[Example in Google Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cKEh-i5XIUoRjFj5gNv9ybWQnBYAgmalPeqea2cF_WI/edit?usp=sharing)