# Excel: Creating a dropdown using two different ranges

Tags: vba, excel

I have following threes excel sheets in a single workbook:

1. Range1_Sheet (A1:A5 contains the data that need to be displayed in
   drop-down)
2. Range2_Sheet (A1:A5 contains the data that need to be
   displayed in drop-down)
3. List_Sheet (This sheet shows a drop-down containing all values that lie in above two ranges).

I successfully did this using one range/sheet. But i was wondering how list can be populated from two different sources?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the same question but only an answer for Google Spreadsheet [Can I create a drop down list with data from multiple sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26666004/can-i-create-a-drop-down-list-with-data-from-multiple-sheets)

Try this - Data Validation:
http://www.contextures.com/xlDataVal05.html

Maybe this?
http://ccm.net/faq/15543-excel-creation-of-dropdown-from-dynamic-list-in-vba

It explains the way with 2 different workbooks but should work with just one workbook and multiple Sheets, too.